# Counting the Number of Capital Letters in Each Row in [R]

Tags: r, counting

I am working in R and I have a column with various upper case and lower case letters in each row. I am trying to count the number of uppercase letters in each row and create a column that shows that number. My column looks like this(just with a lot more rows in the whole data set):

gctaggggggatggttactactGtgctatggactac

gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactac

gcGaggggattggcttac

Is there an easy way to create a column that list the number of upper case letters in each row. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
t = c("gctaggggggatggttactactGtgctatggactac", "gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactac", "gcGaggggattggcttac")  
sapply(regmatches(t, gregexpr("[A-Z]", t, perl=TRUE)), length)
```

Answer (score 1):

using the `plyr` and `stringr`

```
ldply(str_match_all(t,"[A-Z]"),length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using str_count:

t <- c("gctaggggggatggttactactGtgctatggactac", "gGaagggacggttactaCgTtatggactac", "gcGaggggattggcttac")

str_count(t, "[A-Z]")
```

Comment: which packages is it from?

Comment: From stringr, which is included in tidyverse